# Cuál es la forma correcta de concatenar un valor a href

Tags: php, html

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de concatenar un valor a href si el valor a concatenar depende del valor de un radio button?

```
<td>
<div class="radio" id="divRadios" method="post">
 <label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="<?php echo $row_rs_ser['Id_ServicioB']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rs_ser['Descripcion']; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $row_rs_ser['Nombre'];?> <?php echo $row_rs_ser['Apellido_Paterno'];?>  <?php echo $row_rs_ser['Apellido_Materno'];?></td>

  </tr>
<?php } while ($row_rs_ser = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_ser)); ?>

<p align= "center">
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href='EditarSer.php?Id_ServicioB='">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" ></span> Modificar </button>

<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='Confirmar.php?Id_ServicioB='">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span> Eliminar </button>

</p>
```

Comment: Deberias de poner el codigo de lo que has intentado

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hola, coloca el fragmento de código en el que tienes problemas y con gusto te ayudamos

Comment: Creo que no que no puedo agregar el codigo por caracteres, disculpen no se usar este medio...me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Creo que no puedo añadir el codigo por el numero de caracteres, como lo comparto?

Comment: la verdad no entiendo lo que quieres hacer xDD, pero parece que lo que necesitas es con javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Esto no es algo que hagas con PHP porque es en el lado del cliente. Vas a necesitar usar JavaScript para detectar qué radio button se ha seleccionado y cambiar el href en consecuencia.

Sin entrar a considerar tu código (que contiene numerosos errores que harán que el HTML generado no sea válido), podrías hacer algo como esto en JavaScript (comentado y en JavaScript puro porque no sé si estás usando algo como jQuery, aunque me imagino que sí porque usas Bootstrap):

```
// seleccionamos todos los radio buttons con clase optradio
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("[name=optradio]");

// a cada uno de ellos
for (let x = 0; x < radios.length; x++) {

  // le asociamos un controlador de evento para el click
  radios[x].addEventListener("click", function() {

    // que actualiza la URL de los onclick con el valor del radio button pulsado
    document.querySelector(".btn.btn-info").setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='EditarSer.php?Id_ServicioB=" + this.value + "'");
    document.querySelector(".btn.btn-danger").setAttribute("onclick",  "location.href='Confirmar.php?Id_ServicioB=" + this.value + "'");
  });
}
```

---

Aqui lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("[name=optradio]");

for (let x = 0; x < radios.length; x++) {
  radios[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    document.querySelector(".btn.btn-info").setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='EditarSer.php?Id_ServicioB=" + this.value + "'");
    document.querySelector(".btn.btn-danger").setAttribute("onclick",  "location.href='Confirmar.php?Id_ServicioB=" + this.value + "'");
  });
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">Servicio 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2">Servicio 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Servicio 3</label>

<p align="center">
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href='EditarSer.php?Id_ServicioB='">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" ></span> Modificar </button>

<td>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='Confirmar.php?Id_ServicioB='">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span> Eliminar </button>

</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación la verdad casi no sé de estructuras ni nada, xD!! Pero lo pude solucionar, creo que el detalle es que no me supe explicar...Aprovechando que haz respondido, no me podrías ayudar a exportar una imagen de php a excel...bueno es que ahí si no tengo ni idea, si sabes de alguna sintaxis te agradecería la agregaras y me la explicaras...gracias de antemano !